# issue binding and validating checkbox using vee-validate and yup

Tags: vue.js, yup, vee-validate

I'm using vee-validate with yup for the scheme I have a bool field and I want to bind it to an input of type checkbox but I get the following error `accept must be a` boolean `type, but the final value was: "on"`
[please see this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vee-validate-v4-checkboxes-jkc8yr?file=src/App.vue)